# Modify theme of a ListFragment to be different from the activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically I want to set my activity's theme in the manifest as follows:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

And I want my activity to load up a ListFragment with the theme, Theme.Holo.Dialog (defined in my own style), however I can't just call setStyle(....) in my fragment as I could if it were a DialogFragment.

I believe that I should be able to use a ContextThemeWrapper but I'm having trouble understanding the calls I need to make. So far in my onCreateView I have:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater newInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.DialogThemeSelector));
    View inflatedView = newInflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites_print, container, false);
    .....
```

But this is not working. Thanks in advance. Peter.

**Edit ** Posting style:

```
<style name="DialogThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try getting a new `LayoutInflater` instead of converting the provided one, like so:

```
Context newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.DialogThemeSelector);
LayoutInflater newInflater = (LayoutInflater) newContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View inflatedView = newInflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites_print, container, false);
```

If that doesn't work, I would suspect that there may be something missing in your `style`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately didn't work. My activity was transluscent (as expected) but the content of my layout (favourites_print) was simply overlaid on top of the underlying visible app and stretched to fill the width of the device so not taking the dialog style.

Answer (score 1):

I just do it the naive way:  I define my list item layouts in XML, using the `style` attribute, and it  seems to work.  My list items are not so much concerned with whether they are in a fragment or not.  I have not tried styling the fragment itself, but since the list items are the only thing in it, styling them seems sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, although I do want the ListFragment 'dialog' to adopt the holo theme, and no just the list item entries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but can't you just set the theme in the manifest for the activity that holds the listfragment?

Edit: After looking into it my best advice is to look at the source of dialogfragment and try to replicate the behavior in your own customfragment.

OR

Start your fragment up in a new fragmentactivity =/

Comment: I specifically need the activity to have the `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` theme and couldn't get away with setting its theme to be the dialog one. If my activity loads up a `DialogFragment` then I can call `setStyle` to set its theme to be Holo.Dialog, but as mentioned there is no `setStyle` method available for a `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); instead of android: theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

And put in the manifest targetSdkVersion="14" for use Theme.Holo.

Comment: Although I do need the activity to be translucent